# Update last inserted document in mongodb if criteria exceeds threshold

Tags: mongodb

I have a use case where I want to modify document which was first inserted but only if the documents matching the criteria exceeds threshold. For example: I just want to maintain 10 last document of user with certain data. Hence want to modify the document which was inserted first when cap of 10 reaches.

1) If I do it by checking count first and then fetching id of last document by updatedAt date then operation will not be atomic. As some other process can also find that document and start modifying it.

I was thinking about wrapping query and update in same statement but cannot figure out how to check document size criteria.

DB: MongoDB

Comment: Maybe writing your own function, which would first check size and then write something will be solution : [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) .

Comment: Looking for a better approach